# CMake: Read build number from file to set a variable

Tags: cmake, build-numbers

I'm working on a project where the build number is stored in a file called 'BuildNumber.txt' at the root of the project.  What I'd like to do is have CMake read the number from this file and set a variable that can be applied to a header file.

#### setup.h.in

```
#define build_number "@BUILD_NUMBER@";
```

Using configure_file, it's possible to replace placeholders in an .in file like above with a CMake variable.  Is it possible to get CMake to read in the number from BuildNumber.txt into a variable?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the CMake command `file (STRINGS ...)` for that purpose. Assuming the build number is located in the file `BuildNumber.txt` in a single line, the following command will read it into the CMake variable `BUILD_NUMBER`:

```
file (STRINGS "BuildNumber.txt" BUILD_NUMBER)
```

Also see the [file command reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html?highlight=strings).

Comment: See also the "file(READ" command. You can read the whole file into a variable, and then do other string manipulations on it if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know your OS, but I assune that you are using Windows or Linux.

```
if (UNIX)
  set (show_contents_prog cat)
elseif (WIN32)
  set (show_contents_prog type)
endif (WIN32)

execute_process(COMMAND ${show_contents_prog} input.txt OUTPUT_VARIABLE file_contents)
```

I think this may help.